# Trigonometric identities

Tags: special-functions, trigonometric-sums

In the rant I wrote at

http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/trigonometric+identities+and+the+irrationality+of+pi

I asked: Are these four identities the first four terms in a sequence that continues?

This referred to the identities in the last bullet point above that question.

While we're at it, is there any intuitive geometric interpretation of the identity involving $f_2$?

OK, here are the functions involved:

$$
\begin{align}
f_0(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots) & = \sum_{\text{even }n \ge 0} (-1)^{n/2} \sum_{|A| = n} \prod_{i\in A} \sin\theta_i\prod_{i\not\in A}\cos\theta_i \\
f_1(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots) & = \sum_{\text{odd }n \ge 1} (-1)^{(n-1)/2} \sum_{|A| = n} \prod_{i\in A} \sin\theta_i\prod_{i\not\in A}\cos\theta_i \\
f_2(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots) & = \sum_{\text{even }n \ge 2} (-1)^{(n-2)/2} n \sum_{|A| = n} \prod_{i\in A} \sin\theta_i\prod_{i\not\in A}\cos\theta_i \\
f_3(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots) & = \sum_{\text{odd }n \ge 3} (-1)^{(n-3)/2} (n-1) \sum_{|A| = n} \prod_{i\in A} \sin\theta_i\prod_{i\not\in A}\cos\theta_i \\
f_4(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots) & = \sum_{\text{even }n \ge 4} (-1)^{(n-4)/2} n(n-2) \sum_{|A| = n} \prod_{i\in A} \sin\theta_i\prod_{i\not\in A}\cos\theta_i \\
f_5(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots) & = \sum_{\text{odd }n \ge 5} (-1)^{(n-5)/2} (n-1)(n-3) \sum_{|A| = n} \prod_{i\in A} \sin\theta_i\prod_{i\not\in A}\cos\theta_i \\
f_6(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots) & = \sum_{\text{even }n \ge 6} (-1)^{(n-6)/2} n(n-2)(n-4) \sum_{|A| = n} \prod_{i\in A} \sin\theta_i\prod_{i\not\in A}\cos\theta_i \\
f_7(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots) & = \sum_{\text{odd }n \ge 7} (-1)^{(n-7)/2} (n-1)(n-3)(n-5) \sum_{|A| = n} \prod_{i\in A} \sin\theta_i\prod_{i\not\in A}\cos\theta_i \\
& \,\,\,\vdots
\end{align}
$$
In each function the coefficient kills off the terms involving values of $n$ smaller than the index, so that for example we could have said "$\text{odd }n \ge 1$" instead of $\text{odd }n \ge 7$ and it would be the same thing.

Now some facts:

- Each $f_k$ is a symmetric function of $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots$.
- $0$ is an identity element for each of these functions, in the sense that $f_k(0,\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots) = f_k(\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots).$
- Let $\lfloor k\rfloor_\text{even}= 2\lfloor k/2\rfloor$ be the "even floor" of $k,$ i.e. the largest even integer not exceeding $k.$ Then \begin{align}
  & f_k(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots) - f_k(\theta_1+\theta_2,\theta_3,\dots) \\[8pt]
  = {} & \begin{cases}
  \lfloor k \rfloor_\text{even} \cdot \sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2 f_{k-2}(\theta_3,\theta_4,\dots) & \text{if } k\ge2, \\[6pt]
  \quad 0 & \text{if } k = 0\text{ or } 1.
  \end{cases}
  \end{align}

Now the sequence of identities:
$$
\begin{align}
f_0 & = \cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 + \cdots) \\
f_1 & = \sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 + \cdots) \\
\text{If } \sum_{i=1}^\infty \theta_i = \pi,\text{ then }
f_2 & = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sin^2\theta_i=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^\infty (1-\cos(2\theta_i))\\
\text{If } \sum_{i=1}^\infty \theta_i = \pi,\text{ then }
f_3 & = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sin(2\theta_i)
\end{align}
$$
The QUESTION is whether these are the first four identities in a sequence that continues beyond this point.

Comment: Please try to make your question self-contained by not including a link that the reader must click on in order to parse it.  This will greatly increase the readership of your question and thus the likelihood of getting a good answer.  

Comment: Looking at the question and the answer below, I was intrigued how all these "trigonometric identities" could imply "the irrationality of pi". I am disappointed: there is nothing about irrationality nor about pi there... :-(
  

Comment: Actually, if you're looking only at the question and not at the external link, you won't see any of that, and the external link has its own external link to a Wikipedia article that contains Mary Cartwright's proof of the irrationality of $\pi$, so I am somewhat guilty of non-self-containment as suggested above.

Comment: The nLab page is really hard to read.

Comment: Michael, you still have a chance to edit your question by adding the necessary contents and, of course, the trig identity itself.

Comment: OK, I'll do that soon.

Comment: OK, I've added that stuff.

Comment: No one's answered the actual question yet.  Here's a psychological question.  The definitions of $f_0, f_1, f_2, \dots$ in terms of $\left{\,\sum_{|A|=n} \prod_{i\in A} \sin\theta_i\prod_{i\not\in A}\cos\theta_i\,\right\}_{n=0}^\infty$ are given above.  I also found the definitions of the latter expressions in terms of $f_0, f_1, f_2, \dots$ (and those are _not_ stated anywhere on this page).  Before doing this, I _suspected_ these would be simpler than the definitions stated above, in particular having all plus signs and no minus signs.  And so they were.  So why would I suspect that?

Comment: So one can neither edit one's comments nor copy and paste as a new comment and then edit before posting it.  A bug.

Comment: OK, let's see if I can post the expression that should have appeared where the illegible thing is in my comment above, which I can't fixed because of an obnoxious software bug:

$\left\{\,\sum_{|A| = n} \prod_{i\in A} \sin\theta_i\prod_{i\not\in A}\cos\theta_i\,\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$



Answer (score 2):

With binomial theorem, the products on the right have closed form $$ \sum_{|A|=n} \prod_{i \in A} \sin \theta_i \prod_{i \notin A} \cos \theta_i = \prod_{i=1}^n ( \sin \theta_i + \cos \theta_i )^n = \prod_{i=1}^n \sqrt{2} \sin (\theta_i + \pi/4)^n$$
So we'll let $x = \sin \theta + \cos \theta$ so the first sum looks like
$$ \sum_{n \geq 0,\text{ even}} (-1)^{n/2} \prod_{i=1}^n x_i = 1 - x_1x_2 + x_1x_2x_3x_4 - \dots$$
This is not symmetric in the x's.

Comment: John, I don't think this is right. What is true is that
$$f_0+if_1=\prod_j(\cos\theta_j+i\sin\theta_j)$$
from which the $f_0$ and $f_1$ identities drop out immediately.

Comment: The _first two_ identities are of course universally known.  The third one might be entirely novel for all I know.  The simplest non-degenerate special case of the fourth one can at least be facetiously referred to as "well known", and possibly is actually well known within certain communities---I don't really know.  (For the sake of at least a little bit of "self-containment", the simplest non-degenerate special case of the fourth one says that if $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi$ then $4\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma = \sin(2\alpha) + \sin(2\beta) + \sin(2\gamma)$.)

Comment: Yeah I misread the A as running through subsets of {1, 2, \dots, n}.  In fact A runs through all n-element subsets of the natural numbers.